# driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(..)) Selenium is not working in Windows 10

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, css-selectors, windows-10

I'm having issues with the CSS selector in [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) and [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10). The tag seems to be incorrect. How can I fix it?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ById;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Locator2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\abhij\\Desktop\\seliniumjars\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&.intl=us&.lang=en-       US&.done=https%3a//mail.yahoo.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-username']")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='login-username']]")).sendKeys("asdfasd");

        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='login1']")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='login1']")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[id='login-username']]' is not a valid selector

Comment: not able to get css selector work using selinium , the tag is right not sure what i am missing

Comment: below is the output i am getting

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[id='login-username']]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Did you read the error message? What does it say?

Comment: Is the "`lang=en-       US&.done`" part (with the spaces) in the original?

Comment: OK, we will never know. The OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*).

Answer (score 3):

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[id='login-username']]' is not a valid selector

The error is absolutely correct, because your `cssSelector` is incorrect. Just omit the last `]` square bracket which is extra and try as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='login-username']")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
```

You can also use the [`#id CSS selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) to locate an element with their `id` attribute value using `cssSelector` as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#login-username")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
```

[To learn more about the CSS selector, follow this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Selenium also locate an element using the `id` attribute value of an element directly, so you can locate this element using [`By.id()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id-java.lang.String-) as well as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
```

Comment: Thanks saurabh..got it